# Dependency Property to nested grid visibility?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I have a view which exposes a map control:

```
 <controls:OnlineMapControl                                     
       x:Name="OnlineMapControl"                                        
       PanVisibility="Collapsed"
       Margin="0,-5,0,0"
       Background="{DynamicResource DocumentAreaBrush}">
 </controls:OnlineMapControl>
```

in my OnlineMapControl usercontrol the code contains another userControl. I'm trying to set the visibility of this secondry control:

```
<onlineMapControls:NavigationControls Map="{Binding ElementName=tileCanvas}" Visibility="{Binding PanVisibility, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
```

In the code behind of OnlineMapControl I've exposed a dependency property:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Identifies the PanVisibility dependency property.
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty PanVisibilityProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("PanVisibility", typeof(Visibility), typeof(OnlineMapControl));

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the PanVisibility.
        /// </summary>
        public Visibility PanVisibility
        {
            get { return (Visibility)GetValue(PanVisibilityProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PanVisibilityProperty, value); }
        }
```

In my view I am getting a 'The member 'PanVisibility' is not recognized or is nor accessible' what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Use `TemplateBinding` instead of `Binding`. Or, try to set `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits` in your DP definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TemplatedParent is usable only in a ControlTemplate and from what you said you aren't defining any ControlTemplate, only Content to a UserControl. You should use the FindAncestor mode:

```
Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type controls:OnlineMapControl}}, Path=PanVisibility}"
```

Comment: The property Path was not found in RelativeSource?

Comment: @Hardgraf forgot a bracket, added it